# JOLT transformation using condition on different keys

Tags: json, jolt

Can you please assist me with the below as I am new to JOLT Transformation.

I have an input JSON in the below format.

My requirement is to check

- if the `"id"` inside `"playBot"` is **`PROGRAM`** , then include
  `"billID" : "1800-A"` inside `"header"`.
- if `"id"` **is not** **`PROGRAM`** (*any other value other than `PROGRAM`*) , then do
  not include `billID`.

Input :

```json
{
  "playBot" : {
    "id" : "PROGRAM",
    "source" : "TestUser",
    "dateTime" : "01-09-2024 13:24:42"
  },
  "header" : {
    "activityID" : "4100",
    "memberID" : "User-ABC",
    "billID" : "1800-A"
  }
}
```

Desired Output for **1**st case :

```json
{
  "playBot" : {
    "id" : "PROGRAM",
    "source" : "TestUser",
    "dateTime" : "01-09-2024 13:24:42"
  },
  "header" : {
    "activityID" : "4100",
    "memberID" : "User-ABC",
    "billID" : "1800-A"
  }
}
```

Desired Output for **2**nd case :

```json
{
  "playBot" : {
    "id" : "TEST",
    "source" : "TestUser",
    "dateTime" : "01-09-2024 13:24:42"
  },
  "header" : {
    "activityID" : "4100",
    "memberID" : "User-ABC"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this **shift** transformation spec which includes conditional logic within the lines starting from the node `"header"`

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&", // "playBot" object
      "header": {
        "billID": {
          "@2,playBot.id": { // go 2 levels up the tree to grab the value of "playBot.id"
            "PROGRAM": {
              "@2": "&4.billID" // &4 prefixes the attribute by "header" by going 4 levels up the tree
                                // while copying the value of billID through using @2
            },
            "": "" // else case in order the attribute "billID" to be vanished 
          }
        },
        "*": "&1.&" // &1 prefixes the attribute by "header" 
      }
    }
  }
]
```